# How to take a string with commas and spaces and store in array variable

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have this code:

```
        tvData1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvData1);
    tvData2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvData2);
    tvData3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvData3);
    GetData data= new GetData();
    try {
        SharedPreferences getName = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        String name = getName.getString("name", "");
        String returned = data.getData(name); //Gets data from internet
        String[] dataSplit = returned.split(",");
        for(int i = 0; i < dataSplit.length; i++){
            String stringData1 = dataSplit[0];
            String stringData2 = dataSplit[1];
            String stringData3 = dataSplit[2];

            tvData1.setText(stringData1);
            tvData2.setText(stringData2);
            tvData3.setText(stringData3);
        }
```

well, the string gotten from the internet is like this:

```
"1,2,3 4,5,6"
```

and where that space is between 3 and 4 actually shows in a new line like:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

but basically the result i want is

```
stringData1 = 1
stringData2 = 2
stringData3 = 3
stringData4 = 4
etc...
```

instead of:

```
stringData1 = 1
stringData2 = 2
stringData3 = 3 4
```

which is what it's doing now.

also another irrelevant problem I seem to be having is tvData2 will not setText no matter what, even if i do tvData2.setText("Some Text");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String`'s `split()` method takes a regular expression. So possibly you could have a character class in the expression that would split on both commas and new-line characters. Perhaps the following would work. (*Edit: Just tested it and it does work for me.*)

```
String[] dataSplit = returned.split("[,\n]");
```

Another option could be to use the shortcut for white space, to split on *all* whitespace characters: `\s`. (Note that you need to escape the `\` character:

```
String[] dataSplit = returned.split("[,\\s]");
```

Tested and this also works, on the string `"1,2,3\n4,5,6"`.

Comment: Ok, I will try these once =o). For some reason my code is deciding to not pull any data from the internet or something and not getting past the try so I can't get any results from it at the moment. But I really appreciate the both of you =o)

Comment: No problem. In the meantime, you could do what I did and test it on a hard-coded string, i.e. set `returned = "1,2,3\n4,5,6";` and then try your code, just to see that it works as you expect once the networking bits of your code are sorted out.

Comment: Ok, when I try [",\n"] [",\\s"] and [",\\s+"], I keep getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: You are putting the brackets (`[]`) on the outside. They should be on the inside. So instead of `[",\n"]`, you should write `"[,\n]"`, for example.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks. I went to look at it after reading your comment and I actually left out the brackets all together. Thank you very much for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Should work...

```
   returned.split("[,\\s]+");
```

Comment: The "+" character in your character class splits `returned` where a plus character occurs in the string. I think you meant something like `"[,\\s]+"`?